# How to extract sub-sequence pattern from multiple segment sequences

Tags: python, r, pattern-matching, data-science, cluster-analysis

I have a problem about how to extract observed similar patterns from sequences.

I give an example to describe it as below.

Let's say we have a segment sequence, I got its length and value.

Value sequence:  2 3 4 3 2 ... 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 8 2 8 2 ...

Length sequence: 4 2 1 2 4 ... 6 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 5 2 5 ...

I draw it.

We may observe some patterns marked by red rectangles.

[image]

I have many sequences like this, there are may be many other patterns exist in all sequences (I don't know), How can I extract all of them and summarize (count) them? Besides, I am not just looking for the exactly same pattern, take the first rectangle sequence `2 3 4 3 2` as example, there may be `2 3 5 3 2`, I think they are similar and should be classified into one category.

Thanks in advance if there are suggestions (useful methods, techniques) or even solutions.

Best,

Shixiang

Comment: this seems like an alingment problem . this is a traditional problem in genetics. search for tools like BLAST (basic lokal alingment tool) or bowtie2 (availible in conda)

Comment: @user12256545 Thanks for your suggestions. However, I don't know how to apply it to solve my problem. From https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi, I cannot find any method can target my question.